# App is being divided into 3 parts

Tags: android

Why is this is happening? That's an code error from .xml or from Java?

That's my app, it is divided into 3 parts (every part is a layout that is also an App) and I don't know why]

[image]

This app is part of my project for college. Ive used my partners activity and then this error appeared right after the import.
Probably this error appeared because of the import. Im not sure about what I have to do now and Im really new at Android programming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.carro.robo.mobile.ufj.approbo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainBluetoothActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PairedDevices"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainBluetoothActivity" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DiscoveredDevices"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainBluetoothActivity" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Tela_bemVindo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CriacaoQuestoes">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

That is my .xml code. Android Version: 19 (KitKat 4.4)

Answer (score 1):

Your app can have more than 1 item in the launcher.  Every Activity that has a launcher intent filter gets an entry in it.  Yours has 3.  If you don't want them to be in the launcher, remove the launcher intent filter from the ones you don't want to show up.